# Adding jars to tomcat's lib folder on ec2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, memcached, tomcat6

How to add jar files to tomcat's lib folder running on ec2 linux instances? I have already installed tomcat6 on ec2 instance. I want to add jars for memcahed session manager jars into tomcat's lib folder. Can any one tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. *Temporary*: Just scp those jars to the tomcat folder. But if you instanciate a new machine, you will have to do it again.
2. *Permanent*: After step#1, make an image of the instance. This will preserve the jar for all the instances that you launch from this image.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to have something like ant deployment script, which is deploying/copying your app.
It copies WEB-INF/lib/*.jars or common jars to Tomcat folder

You can also use  Beanstalk (ec2+Tomcat) and manage it from Amazon console(uploading you app with jars).